# How do I structure templates and static files in a django project?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm pretty confused at how to structure my project such that relative paths in html files work.  For example, let's say I have `index.html`, and in it, I have an image.  I have an images folder called `img` and in it I have `cat.png`.

So, inside my index.html, I have `<img src='img/cat.png'>`.  Now, all of these files are in my project's `static` folder, with `STATIC_URL='/static/'`, so they get served statically, and it works great: since index.html is in `/static/`, then `img/cat.png` is found with no problem.

***But here's the problem:***

Let's say I want to make index.html a template.  So I define a route for it, say `/appname/index.html` in `urls.py`, and I make a view for that route in `views.py` which renders that template with whatever data I need to get into it.  Great, now I serve that rendered template, and it is at `/appname/index.html`.  But this means that it will look for all those static files in that path, so for example, it will look for the cat image at `/appname/img/cat.png` instead of `/static/img/cat.png`.

Of course I could go through my `index.html` and change every single relative path to an absolute path, but that isn't great, because then I have to worry more about what will happen if I move files around.  In my particular case, I found that some javascript I'm using loads some CSS dynamically, and I don't want to go in and edit the javascript to all use absolute paths as well.

So what's up?  Is Django just bad at serving static content, and I should be using nginx or apache for that instead?  I know Django is supposed to be able to function as a full production server, so I don't know what's up here.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a combination of your templating language, middleware, and some configuration. Directions for how to do this can be found here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

> 1. Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.
> 2. In your settings file, define `STATIC_URL`, for example:
>
>    `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
> 3. In your templates, either hardcode the url like `/static/my_app/myexample.jpg` or, preferably, use the static template
>      tag to build the URL for the given relative path by using the
>      configured `STATICFILES_STORAGE` storage (this makes it much easier
>      when you want to switch to a content delivery network (CDN) for
>      serving static files).
>
>    `{% load staticfiles %}`
>
>    `img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"`
> 4. Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example `my_app/static/my_app/myimage.jpg.`